# Why searchkick is returning only distinct values on id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, search, activerecord

I have a rails model that is the result of sql view. This is union of same table and somethimes happend that i have two rekords with same id but different one column, what is correct. The problem is that i want to use searchkick in this model. So i add searchkick to rails model but after call method `.search.results` returns records that are uniq by id.
So for example we can call it `ExtendedModel`

```rb
class ExtendedModel
  searchkick
end
```

then in the console

```rb
> ExtendedModel.pluck(:id)
=>[1, 1] # this retunrs [1, 1]
# but when call search on it then returns only uniq
> ExtendedModel.search.results.pluck(:id)
=>[1]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `searchkick` treats model `id` as the Elasticsearch document's `_id`. It works like a charm for a conventional setup, but fails in your case where your model has a composite primary key (and non-unique `id`s). As the result, even if you have several models with `id=1` (distinguished by some other column(s)), only one of them is actually indexed. That's why you get only one of them back from search.

As far as I see, Searchkick allows you to define `search_document_id` method for your model, that [will be used as document _id then](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/a761740871849cd7e95f1c78cebd1896f698f45c/lib/searchkick/record_data.rb#L30). Try defining it via your composite key so that all documents' ids would be unique - this should help with having them all indexed properly.

(This might or might not also require a more sophisticated setup with customized mappings and search, but first things first)